# jQuery timer to stop on window change not on iframe focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, mozilla

I have a PTC(Pay to click) site which shows advertiser website inside iframe.
Now i am trying to stop the timer if any user change the window so that i force users to see the advertiser website for a specific peroid of time.

when i used

```
window.onblur & window.onfocus
```

it can work fine if i don't have any iframe in my that window.
But when ever user hover to iframe the window.onblur event runs but i am trying to make sure that if user is inside the windows or in iframe nothing happens.
Only on window change or tab change we can stop the timmer this is what i tried at my level best..

```
    var has_focus = false;
    var timer=0;

    function loading_time() {

        $('iframe').hover(function(){
            has_focus=true;
        });

        $('iframe').click(function(){
            has_focus=true;
        });


        if(has_focus==true){

            timer++;
            $('#ss').text(timer);
        }
            setTimeout("loading_time()", 1000);
    }

    window.onblur = function(){
        has_focus=false;
    }

    window.onfocus = function(){
        has_focus=true;
    }

    loading_time();
```

But still when user goes to the iframe & click on any input fields the focus got damaged & this code will not work.
Also this code have some errors like when user hover to iframe window.blur event occur & it overlap the iframe.hover resulting timer can stop.

I tried everything but unable to make a good logic which will help me to detect the users is on current window or on iframe & if he change the window or tab then i can stop timer.

I want to force user to see the website for particular time.

The above code have many bugs sometime the timer stop even when its watching the iframe site & sometime the timer not get stopped even when i minimize the window.

So now i don't know the thing which i am trying can possible or not because

```
iframe.onfocus
```

not work in jquery i think if this can work then may be i can make a conditon to check both are focus or not & then can do whatever i want to do.

Comment: Try to get the contents of the iframe on load using jQuery and append your script into it before displaying.

Comment: It can't possible as i don't want to change the content of that iframe users have to go to the advertiser sites direclty so that they can also track the visitors.